# How to populate Nested json object C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

Hey all I have a class

```
public class Data {

   string key {get; set;}
   string value {get; set;}
}
public class Employee { 

   string x {get; set;}
   string y {get; set;}
   Data Data {get; set;}
}
```

In Json response I get the below value in string

```json
{
  "Employee":{
  "x": null,
  "y": null,
  "Data" : {
    "key": 1,
    "Value": "hello"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to deserialize this Json string into type Employee I used

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(jsonString);
```

but It only populate the  parent object and nested object data is null, here are results

```json
{
  "Employee":{
  "x": null,
  "y": null,
  "Data" :null
  }
}
```

Does anyone have some good solution to get the nested object value in an efficient way.

Comment: Data is capitalized in your data, but lower case in your model. Same for value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in the incoming Json package. It should be like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Data {
       public string key {get; set;}
       public string value {get; set;}
    }
    public class Employee { 

       public string x {get; set;}
       public string y {get; set;}
       public Data Data {get; set;}
    }
    
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonString = @"{
              ""x"": null,
              ""y"": null,
              ""Data"" : {
                ""key"": 1,
                ""value"": ""hello""
                }
            }";
            
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(jsonString);
    
            Console.WriteLine(obj.x);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.y);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Data.key);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Data.value);
        }
    }
}
```